# Scaling knot diagram is losing ability to detect crossings

Tags: tikz-knots

My goal is to be able to render knot diagrams in tek and the be able to scale them so that I can place them in environments such as equations. However, when I begin to scale the diagrams so that they are sufficiently small to not look awkward in an equation the diagram is losing it's detection of the crossings. From what I know about how the rendering is done I'm sure that I am running into limitations of the computation. My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.2]
\begin{knot}[
    consider self intersections,
    ignore endpoint intersections = false,
    draft mode = crossings,
    clip width = 2,]
    %flip crossing = #,]
\strand[black, thick](0,0) .. controls +(5,16) and +(5,-16) .. (0,8) .. controls +(5,16) and +(5,-16) .. (0,16);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm hoping that someone with more technical knowledge than me can say whether or not there is hope to get things working or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not realize that would be a problem. Thank you and I believe I have fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I think that the problem does not arise with the syntax from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526054/194703). I tested `scale=0.1`. Assuming you want a smooth plot, is the question still open? (You can always use `\scalebox` to downscale something that works without losing intersections. Of course, this might mean that you need to increase the line width in order to get a reasonable output.)

Comment: Just an observation from iterations, for the code as-is: a) scale = 0.21825 DOES intersect, while scale = 0.21820 does NOT, i.e. numerically the critical point for this set of parameters is somewhere in between.